# how to solve the net beans check out error org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException?

Tags: java, netbeans, environment-variables, project, ubuntu-14.04

As i  checkout my  project in net beans 7.3.1,i got the following error

"org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity"

if you know how to solve this kindly help me out.Since i am new to Ubuntu,also some please help me how to set the environmental variables for Java in Ubuntu?